# get FileInfo for HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, file-io

Is there a simple way to get the `FileInfo` object from an `HttpPostedFileBase`? I realize I can save the file then do something like `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` and then loop through the files looking for my file, but is there any simpler way to do this for a given file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no `FileInfo` associated to an uploaded file. Only the `filename` is sent as parameter as well as the file stream itself. So that's what you could query:

```
HttpPostedFileBase file = ...

string filename = file.FileName;
int fileSize = file.ContentLength;
string contentType = file.ContentType;
using (Stream stream = file.InputStream)
{
    // do something with the file contents here
}
```

To better understand what gets sent from the client I invite you to read the [`multipart/form-data`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2) specification.

The FileInfo object contains things like LastModified and LastAccessed date which is not an information that is sent when a file is uploaded. If you save the file on your web server disk and then retrieve the FileInfo from it bear in mind that what you will be retrieving is the information about this file **on the server** and **not on the client** simply because this information is never sent when a file is uploaded.